# How to retrive data from MySql in SpringBoot using composite primary keys

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

I'm working on a simple spring boot project to retrieve data from a MySQL table where the table will have a composite primary key. This is my MySQL data table

```
id     date              temp

0  2018-12-01 10:20:12    35

1  2018-12-02 10:40:12    38

1  2018-12-01 10:20:12    40
```

In the interface, I created an own method to retrieve a data set for a particular id. But that's showing an error as below:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'demoRepo': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Using named parameters for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.demo.DemoRepo.findAllByMyIdId(int) but parameter 'Optional[:id]' not found in annotated query 'from Sensor where myId.id=:id'!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:176) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:101) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1879) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1268) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:345) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:671) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.onApplicationEvent(DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java:53) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.onApplicationEvent(DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java:35) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:203) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:196) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:161) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:426) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:383) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:945) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:591) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Using named parameters for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.demo.DemoRepo.findAllByMyIdId(int) but parameter 'Optional[:id]' not found in annotated query 'from Sensor where myId.id=:id'!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryMethod.assertParameterNamesInAnnotatedQuery(JpaQueryMethod.java:157) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryMethod.<init>(JpaQueryMethod.java:136) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.DefaultJpaQueryMethodFactory.build(DefaultJpaQueryMethodFactory.java:44) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:100) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1054) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:85) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:258) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:85) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:303) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$6(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:326) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:230) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:271) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:58) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:169) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

The corresponding demoRepo interface class:

```
public interface DemoRepo extends JpaRepository<Sensor, MyId> {

    @Query("from Sensor where myId.id=:id")
    List<Sensor> findAllByMyIdId(@Param(":id") int id);
}
```

The corresponding model classes are below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sensors")
public class Sensor {

    @EmbeddedId
    private MyId myId;
    private int temp;

    public Sensor() {
    }

    public Sensor(MyId myId, int temp) {
        this.myId = myId;
        this.temp = temp;
    }
     /*Getters and setters*/

@Embeddable
public class MyId implements Serializable {

    public int id;
    private String date;

    public MyId() {
    }

    public MyId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public MyId(int id, String date) {
        this.id = id;
        this.date = date;
    }
/*Getters and Setters*/
```

The relevant methods for retrieving data of a particular id in controller class and service class as follows:

```
@GetMapping("/sensors/{id}")
    public List<Sensor> getSensorData(@PathVariable int id){
        return demoService.getOneSensor(id);
    }

 public List<Sensor> getOneSensor(int id){
        List<Sensor> sensors = demoRepo.findAllByMyIdId(id);
        return sensors;
    }
```

Comment: Converted my comment to an answer, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the colon from this annotation: `@Param(":id")`

Colon is only used to mark variables in the query, they are not part of the parameter name.

Answer (score -1):

I think your query is wrong

instead of

```
              @Query("from Sensor where myId.id=:id")
```

Shoulb be something like

```
              @Query("Select * from Sensor where myId.id=id")
```